# Template breaks meteor package

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, package

I have created a package in my meteor app. Which one has a client part. It is getting troubles for using `Template.xxx.events` this code chat.html:

```
<template name="accountEasyChat">
    {{messages}}
    {{> write}}
</template>
<template name="write">
    <input type="text" id="text_message"/><button id="send_message">Enviar</button>
</template>
```

and chat.js

```
Meteor.subscribe('accountEasyChatMessages')

UI.registerHelper('messages',function(){
    Messages.find({}).forEach(function(m){
        messages = messages + m.message
    })
    return messages
});

Template.write.events({
  'click': function(event, template) {
     console.log('test')
  }
});
```

if I comment this:

```
Template.write.events({
      'click': function(event, template) {
         console.log('test')
      }
});
```

Everything works ok.

Answer (score 1):

In `Package.onUse` you need to add a dependency to the package "templating" to get access to `Template`.

By the way, `UI.registerHelper` is deprecated in favor of `Template.registerHelper`.

Comment: I have added but it does not work :( here is the code: https://github.com/kahon/account-easy-chat/blob/master/package.js

Comment: Add also : ```api.imply(['templating'], 'client'); ```

Comment: I have changed it: github.com/kahon/account-easy-chat/blob/master/package.js
 but it still is not working

Comment: @kahonmlg, now I'm guessing, but try adding the html file before the js file using the template. Otherwise, show us the error messages you get.

Comment: Output ` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'events' of undefined` It is like no recognize `Template.write`

Comment: @kahonmlg, I checked your code, the problem is that you have no template named `write` (possible `writeText`?).

Comment: I have changed write fir write text in all code thinking maybe ut could be a reserved word. But it is not the problem.

Comment: @kahonmlg, did you try that in combination with adding the html file before adding the js file? :P

Comment: Yes,anyway chat.html is before to chat.js because of alphabetical order that meteor follow. Even I tried to rename for achat.html. Nothing is happen.

Comment: @kahonmlg, yes in apps the files are loaded in alphabetical order, and html files are loaded before js files. I don't know if this is the case in packages, where you have to provide the load order yourself. In `package.js`, try using `api.addFiles(['client/views/chat.html', 'client/views/chat.js'],'client')` instead of `api.addFiles(['client/views/chat.js', 'client/views/chat.html'],'client')`.

Comment: I just have created package again. Inserting every file little by little. I have change package.js a little too. Now it is working, but I don't know what was wrong. Thank you guys.